# What are ways to optimized LWUIT application?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-resource-editor

I'm running in a bit of OC situation here. I'm developing an application using LWUIT 1.5. So I'm almost done with the application, I've already added transitions in fact. But I noticed that the application is lagging on the phone(My current test phone is a [Nokia C3-00](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_c3-3269.php)). The transitions are starting halfway.

Do you guys have any advise on how do i optimize my application? I know I could use the `Next Form` properties of the `Form`, but I wouldn't want to always show a "splash screen" every time the user will go to another screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nokia's are often very slow with translucent images, any image that contains a translucent image would be pretty slow which includes image borders. Another culprit is overly narrowly cut image borders, there is a workaround for this in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) though.

Remove the theme and create a blank or theme that only uses colors. See if speed improves.

Assuming it does then slowly remove suspect elements from your theme. If it doesn't then see if you load large images etc.